# How to extract version number from the string

Tags: bash

I am new to UNIX.

I have a case that I want to extract version number from these kind of strings (one string at a time) like below, how should I do that?

```
release-2.15-5 > 2.15
release-2.15 > 2.15
2.15 > 2.15
2.15-5 > 2.15
```

I already did `echo release-2.15-5 | cut -f1 -d'-'`, but result is not correct

Comment: Could you use some words to describe the criteria you're using to identify the version number? e.g. "leading letters and dashes should be ignored; trailing dashes onward should be ignored", etc. Additionally, are these strings in a file, or are they output from a command, or as contents of a variable, or??

Comment: `echo release-2.15-5 | cut -f2 -d'-'` would give `2.15`. `cut` numbers the fields from one, not zero.

Comment: Btw, remember that _in general_, version strings can be much more than just <i>x.yy</i>, starting from version numbers with multiple parts, like 5.11.5, or 2.6.3, but also to ones with suffixes separated by other characters, where some mean "a version later than the one numbered", and others "a version _earlier_ than the one numbered", e.g. 1.2.3~beta1 as a pre-version of 1.2.3. So, yeah.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well given that there is not so much context, I would suggest to you to check the `grep` instruction to extract such kind of information. If, for example your input is only of that kind you could use `grep` in the following manner:

```
grep -Eo '[0-9]\.[0-9]+' filename
```

Where:

- `-E` is the flag that indicates that we will use an extended
  regex (check [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Basic-vs-Extended.html) for more info)
- `-o` is the flag that specifies that we only need the exact match to be
  returned when found
- `[0-9]\.[0-9]+` is the regexp that says that we need a digit
  followed by a dot and then one or more trailing digits. Note that the dot character MUST be escaped. Otherwise, the plain dot i.e., `.` would count as 'whichever character'.
- `filename` is the input to grep

In your example, this would return the following:

```
2.15
2.15
2.15
2.15
```

If, on the other hand you just need one of the matches, then you can use also `head` piped to the grep like this:

```
grep -Eo '[0-9]\.[0-9]+' filename | head -1
```

Comment: You need to quote stuff like `[0-9]\.[0-9]+`. Partly because `[` is a glob character, so that may match and expand some existing filename, error out if it doesn't match (depending on shell and settings), but also because an unquoted backslash will be removed by the shell, and `grep` will see an unescaped dot.

Comment: Correct, I forgot the quotes.

Comment: Also, in Bash, you can match regexes within the shell too: `str='release-2.15-5'; re='[0-9]+\.[0-9]+'; if [[ $str =~ $re ]]; then echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"; fi`